# Map of maps - how to keep the inner maps as maps?

Tags: java, hashmap

My goal is to create a map of maps so that I can retrieve info of the outer map by its key and then access its "inner" maps by their keys.

However, when I got each inner map, the map I created originally became an Object and I cannot use key to access its value as I do with the outer map.

To learn from you experts, I would like to know how to keep all the maps as maps.  Or, is it possible at all?

here is my exercise program:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class MapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Object,String> mp=new HashMap<Object, String>();

        // adding or set elements in Map by put method key and value pair
        mp.put(new Integer(2), "Two");
        mp.put(new Integer(1), "One");
        mp.put(new Integer(3), "Three");
        mp.put(new Integer(4), "Four");

        Map<Object,String> mp2=new HashMap<Object, String>();
        mp2.put(new Integer(2), "Two2");
        mp2.put(new Integer(1), "One2");
        mp2.put(new Integer(3), "Three2");
        mp2.put(new Integer(4), "Four2");

        Map<Object,String> mpMaps=new HashMap();

        mpMaps.put("Map1",mp);
        mpMaps.put("Map2",mp2);

        System.out.println("This is a map of Maps:   " + mpMaps); 

        for (int i=0;i<mpMaps.size();i++){
                     ArrayList a = new ArrayList(mpMaps.keySet());
                     Object o=a.get(i);
                     System.out.println("all together: " + mpMaps.size() + "each element is:  " + o + " value: " + mpMaps.get(o));
        }             
    }
}
```

**SOLUTIONS:**

```
   Map<Object,Map<Object,String>
    Map<String, Object> mpMaps=new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

by ameer and sleske

Comment: Think about that another possible solution for your purpose is to have a single hashmap that has as keys pairs of values. This would reduce complexity of the whole thing (also because with actual generics syntax is quite a pain).

Comment: yes, that is nice! thank you!  My need comes from a project that I need to sort a list of maps first, then retrieve the values of each single map for further use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the updated code that seems to work, you need to type the map of maps as `<String, Object>` since mp isn't a string you can't do `<Object, String>`.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Object,String> mp=new HashMap<Object, String>();

        // adding or set elements in Map by put method key and value pair
        mp.put(new Integer(2), "Two");
        mp.put(new Integer(1), "One");
        mp.put(new Integer(3), "Three");
        mp.put(new Integer(4), "Four");

        Map<Object,String> mp2=new HashMap<Object, String>();
        mp2.put(new Integer(2), "Two2");
        mp2.put(new Integer(1), "One2");
        mp2.put(new Integer(3), "Three2");
        mp2.put(new Integer(4), "Four2");

        Map<String, Object> mpMaps=new HashMap<String, Object>();

        mpMaps.put("Map1",mp);
        mpMaps.put("Map2",mp2);

        System.out.println("This is a map of Maps:   " + mpMaps); 

        for (int i=0;i<mpMaps.size();i++){
                     ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>(mpMaps.keySet());
                     Object o=a.get(i);
                     System.out.println("all together: " + mpMaps.size() + "each element is:  " + o + " value: " + mpMaps.get(o));
        }             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternate solution would be to use Commons MultiKey for avoiding map of maps. See details at http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/ and org.apache.commons.collections.keyvalue.MultiKey

Answer (score 5):

Your code does not compile.

One problem is this:

```
Map<Object,String> mpMaps=new HashMap();
mpMaps.put("Map1",mp);
```

This won't work, as you put a Map (`mp`) into a Map whose values need to be `Strings`.

Use  `Map<Object,Map<Object,String>` and you should be fine.

Comment: by redefining the map, should i get a map by Map m = mpMaps.get(key)?  I tried, but still can not get it to work.....

Comment: Yes, you should. If it does not work, edit your question to add the new code and explain exactly what does not work.

Comment: Excellent!  I got it working!  Now, really understand how serious Java is!  A few times, I got code working in Groovy, but when tried on Java, it failed.  It failed because I did not give enough detail of the types!  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example using `HashMap`

```
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> outerMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>>();

    HashMap<String, Object> innerMap1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    HashMap<String, Object> innerMap2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();


    innerMap1.put("Name", "az");
    innerMap1.put("Address", "7 lab");
    innerMap1.put("Age", 40);

    innerMap2.put("Name", "sab");
    innerMap2.put("Address", "bk3");
    innerMap2.put("Age", 35);

    outerMap.put("1",innerMap1);
    outerMap.put("2", innerMap2);
    System.out.println("outerMap = " + outerMap);
```

output:

```
outerMap = {1={Address=7 lab, Age=40, Name=az}, 2={Address=bk3, Age=35, Name=sab}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Object,String> mpMaps=new HashMap();

mpMaps.put("Map1",mp);
```

you'll get an exception with this statement: mp has type Map but you're treating it as a String.

If I understood your question right, you'll either need a reference to the object used as key or you'll need to type cast your key/values.

Answer (score -3):

[image: Example]

This is an example on creating a map of maps.