# creating a map in which value will again be type of map in java

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a map in which key is list of values and matched to one value as shown below basically i want to create a map in which value will again will be of type map

```
Deaswe = DealDate
TradeRe = TradeRef
Deadery = DealDate
Dealdt = DealDate
Traes = TradeRef
TraRef = TradeRef
Daelet = DealDate
TF = TradeRef
```

below is the code to achieve that

```
Map<String, List<String>> dataMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        dataMap.put ("TradeRef", Arrays.asList("TradeRe", "TraRef", "TF", "Traes"));
        dataMap.put ("DealDate", Arrays.asList("Dealdt", "Daelet", "Deadery", "Deaswe"));


        Map<String, String> itemMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); //New map for item->key mapping
        for(String key: dataMap.keySet()) //Get all keys and iterate through
            for(String item: dataMap.get(key)) //For each item in your value list
                itemMap.put(item, key); //Create new mapping item->key
```

now the above map is working fine but over it again i want to create one more map such that as shown below so please advise how can I create a map in which value will be type of my above existing map

```
key     value 

B1      HashMap<String, List<String>>
```

so it would be like

```
B1  -->    Deaswe   --> DealDate
B2 --->    Dealdt   --> DealDate
B1  --->   TradeRe  --> TradeRef
B2  --->   Traes    -->  TradeRef
    folks please advise
```

Comment: Would `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>` be what you want?

Comment: @Thomas yeah please advise how can I make that request you if you could please code and post as I have done that will help to grasp Thanks in advance

Comment: On a second look you might want to use a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`. Implementation should be straight forward, so assuming you already have a value (a Map<String, String>) for `B1` in your outer map, it would be `outer.get("B1").put("Deaswe", "RealDate")`. I'll leave the rest for you.

Comment: @Thomas can you please advise How would I declare such map and how I would iterate over such map  THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can have a map of string (key)and map (value)

example

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> dataMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> itemMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
item="some value";
key="some value";
itemMap.put(item, key);
dataMap.put("TradeRef",itemMap);
```

this is just an exapmle. i'm using a itemmap inside datamap. you can use multiple levels of maps and insert it as the values in each level of map.

you can also refer to this question [Map of maps - how to keep the inner maps as maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120216/map-of-maps-how-to-keep-the-inner-maps-as-maps) and this link http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and

Comment: Thanks but still not able to grasp can you please post the code that will help to grasp more Thanks in advance

Comment: i've edited my answer. let me know if you need any further clarification or help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map of your map containing the list:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> mapOfMapOfStrings =
        new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();
HashMap<String, List<String>> b1Map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
mapOfMapOfStrings.put("B1", b1Map);

HashMap<String, List<String>> b2Map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
mapOfMapOfStrings.put("B2", b2Map);

ArrayList<String> dealDateList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> tradeRefList = new ArrayList<String>();

b1Map.put("Deaswe", dealDateList);
b2Map.put("Dealdt", dealDateList);
b1Map.put("TradeRe", tradeRefList);
b2Map.put("Traes", tradeRefList);

dealDateList.add("DealDate1");
dealDateList.add("DealDate2");
tradeRefList.add("tradeRef1");
tradeRefList.add("tradeRef2");
```